# Querying values from one column with different id (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a form table with these columns

| Record Id | Form Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 'EN' |
| 1 | 101 | 'English' |
| 1 | 102 | 'No' |
| 2 | 100 | 'KR' |
| 2 | 101 | 'Korea' |
| 2 | 102 | 'Ye' |

The database structure is as is and I couldn't already modify so I had to work with this structure.

My problem is on querying the corresponding value for each form id. I've tried this:

**Multiple subquery**

```
WITH CODE AS 
 (SELECT * FROM DUMMY_TABLE  WHERE FORM_ID = 100),
LANGUAGE AS 
 (SELECT * FROM DUMMY_TABLE  WHERE FORM_ID = 101)

SELECT * FROM <main_query>
```

The issue I'm getting are multiple rows for each record and it doesn't seem like an ideal solution to me.

Comment: Assuming what you intended (an example of the result set you want would be helpful), did you try the Pivot function? Having Record ID as the Id, and the FormID value as the columns. That would create a simple data set. Especially if the FormID values list is small and finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 2 options:

- use case to separate the values. The labels on each column can be easily modified. I use MAX to be able to use GROUP BY so as to return one line per record.
- use pivot function
  Again we have to use an aggregate function and can label our columns as we wish.
  See DBfiddle link at bottom for schema and testing.

> ```
> /* Using case */
> SELECT
>   RecordId,
>   MAX(CASE WHEN FormID = 100 
>      THEN Value END) code,
>   MAX(CASE WHEN FormId = 101
>      THEN Value END) language,
>   MAX(CASE WHEN FormId = 102
>       THEN Value END) word
> FROM t
> GROUP BY RecordId;
> ```
>
> ```
> RECORDID | CODE | LANGUAGE | WORD
> -------: | :--- | :------- | :---
>        2 | KR   | Korean   | Ye  
>        1 | EN   | English  | No
> ```

> ```
> /* Using pivot */
> select * from (
>    select RecordId, FormId,Value
>    from  t
> )
> pivot 
> (
>    max(Value)
>    for FormId in (100 code,
>                   101 language,
>                   102 word)
> )
> order by RecordId
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> RECORDID | CODE | LANGUAGE | WORD
> -------: | :--- | :------- | :---
>        1 | EN   | English  | No  
>        2 | KR   | Korean   | Ye
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e1b08db6f7972e5d1424cb6b78354e4d)*